# Google Maps Streetview marker changes location based on vantage point

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I am attempting to show a google maps marker via satellite view and street view at the same time. However, the marker placed on street view seems to change location (be slightly offset) depending on where along the street you are looking at it. In the examples below, you can see in one angle the marker is successfully on the grass and the satellite view matches the street view. However, if I navigate down the road one step, the marker is now on the driveway, despite the satellite view indicating otherwise. The same marker is used for all examples.

Any thoughts?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lpgoex2/

```
    const startPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(33.82444502161826, -84.32112795727612);

    // Aerial view map with marker
    var locationMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location'), {
        center: startPosition,
        zoom: 21,
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });
    locationMap.setTilt(0)

    var locationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: startPosition,
        map: locationMap
    });

    // Street view map with marker
    var viewMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('view'), {
        center: startPosition,
        zoom: 14
    });
    var viewMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: startPosition,
        map: viewMap,
    });

    // Update streetview to look at the marker
    var panorama = viewMap.getStreetView();
    const panoramaService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
    panorama.setVisible(true);
    panoramaService.getPanoramaByLocation(startPosition, 100, function(streetViewPanoramaData, streetViewStatus) {
        if (streetViewStatus == "OK") {

            let heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(streetViewPanoramaData.location.latLng, startPosition);
            const position = streetViewPanoramaData.location.latLng;
            panorama.setPosition(position)

            panorama.setPov({
                heading: heading,
                pitch: 0
            });

            panorama.setZoom(1); // Fix bug to make marker visible https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830290
            panorama.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

[image: good example]
[image: bad example]

**Note**: An [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148387854) has been opened.

Comment: What about posting a [mcve]?

Comment: good call @MrUpsidown!. i've added one (https://jsfiddle.net/6Lpgoex2/)

Comment: Seems very accurate when you stand next to it and a bit less when further away. I suppose this is due to the way the spherical panoramas are rendered. On steep roads, I've seen bizarre things too. I don't know the level of accuracy though and not sure if it is communicated. You can always search for an existing [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853%20status:open) or open a new one.

Comment: I have edited your question to include a link to the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148387854) and added a link to your question in the issue tracker. It's always worth linking the two.